# Change CSS of an object that I'm listening to an event Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, events, object, mouseover

I am listening an event from an object in Javascript, and I don't know how to change the CSS. I tried to pass the object in the function parameters but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
auxiliar.addEventListener('mouseover',function mouseOver(){
   console.log("debug mouse over");
   //Here I want change the CSS class of auxiliar
});
```

Any Idea?? Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way is JQuery:

Change the CSS directly:

```
document.getElementById('YourID').addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
   $(this).css("color", "#f00"); //get the object this function is running on
});
```

Add a Class:

```
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
   $(this).addClass("NewClass"); //give your object a clsas you can target in CSS
});
```

And of course there's standard JavaScript as well:

```
var MyObject = document.getElementById('a');
MyObject.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
   MyObject.className = MyObject.className + " NewClass";
});
```

make sure not to add it infinitely often though.

Comment: Thank u! Finally I do whit jQuery